# Is there a keyboard command for 'show desktop'?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Like Windows, I want to hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to jump to the desktop or minimize all windows. I don't see command like that in Keyboard Shortcuts. Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, it's set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. You can set your own shortcut by going to *System → Settings → Keyboard Shortcuts* and changing "Hide all normal windows and set focus to the desktop" located under **"window management"**:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the whole post. It's listed in the keyboard shortcuts as "Hide all normal windows and set focus to the desktop" located under "window management" so you should be able to change it to the super+d if you want.

Comment: That did it! I kept looking in Desktop under shortcuts thinking it would be there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried both <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to see the default for Ubuntu 14.04 and neither worked. Then again, I didn't bother to change the default setting.  Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, thats what worked for me.

btw, the <kbd>Super</kbd> key for any computer with Windows automatically installed is the key that looks like the Windows logo.